# Zend Soap Client returns null with valid XML last response

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap-client

I am having an issue when trying to access my own PHP Soap Service with PHP. I am using Zend_Soap for both the client and server.

Basically, the result I get from the client is null. However if I look at the last response, it contains the expected, correct XML. So the client is failing to convert the xml to a php object (in my test case, a simple int) for use.

my wsdl looks like this

```
<definitions name="SOAP_Model_soaphandler" targetNamespace="http://website.com/appldev/applications/public/SOAP/index/soap">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://website.com/appldev/applications/public/SOAP/index/soap"/>
    </types>
    <portType name="SOAP_Model_soaphandlerPort">
        <operation name="test">
            <documentation>Returns list of all products in database</documentation>
            <input message="tns:testIn"/>
            <output message="tns:testOut"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="test2">
            <documentation>Adds new product to database</documentation>
            <input message="tns:test2In"/>
            <output message="tns:test2Out"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="SOAP_Model_soaphandlerBinding" type="tns:SOAP_Model_soaphandlerPort">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="test">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://website.com/appldev/applications/public/SOAP/index/soap#test"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://website.com/appldev/applications/public/SOAP/index/soap"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://website.com/appldev/applications/public/SOAP/index/soap"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="test2">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://website.com/appldev/applications/public/SOAP/index/soap#test2"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://website.com/appldev/applications/public/SOAP/index/soap"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://website.com/appldev/applications/public/SOAP/index/soap"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="SOAP_Model_soaphandlerService">
        <port name="SOAP_Model_soaphandlerPort" binding="tns:SOAP_Model_soaphandlerBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://website.com/appldev/applications/public/SOAP/index/soap"/>
        </port>
    </service>
    <message name="testIn"/>
    <message name="testOut">
        <part name="return" type="xsd:int"/>
    </message>
    <message name="test2In">
        <part name="id" type="xsd:int"/>
    </message>
    <message name="test2Out">
        <part name="return" type="soap-enc:Array"/>
    </message>
</definitions>
```

and my response looks like this

```
<env:envelope xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns1="http://website.com/appldev/applications/public/SOAP/index/soap" xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <env:body xmlns:rpc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-rpc">
        <ns1:testresponse env:encodingstyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
            <rpc:result>return</rpc:result>
            <return xsi:type="xsd:int">7</return>
        </ns1:testresponse>
    </env:body>
</env:envelope>
```

but

```
$result=$client->test(); 
var_dump($result);
```

outputs NULL.

Any ideas? It looks like it should be working to me, but I am not an expert in how the soap client works. Perhaps there is an issue with the namespace or something? I really dont know. It seems like it should be working fine. For reference, I followed this guide to get things up and running:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/x-zsoap/index.html

I suppose I could always just manually get the response from the xml, but I am hoping to figure out why the client is not doing so for me.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to remove soap temp file: `/tmp/wsdl*`, then restart the webserver.
Hope this help.

Comment: Where is the this directory?

Answer (score -1):

It's kind of late, but just for the record verify the declaration of the method in the service class, the comments should be like this

/**
* Service
*
* @param type $varname
* @return type
*/

There must be /** and and one space, and then the rest. Otherwise null will be returned.

Good Luck!